# ¿Cómo obtener el valor de retorno del método onPostExecute de mi AsyncTask en mi Activity?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Hola amigos tengo una clase `Asynctask` y quiero obtener el resultado del método `onPostExecute` que este genera al terminar en mi `Activity` principal `MainActivity` ya que las clases son separadas alguien sabe como hacerlo? ya que seguí los pasos de una posible solución en *StackOverFlow en ingles*:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a

Pero me marca el siguiente error:

```
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                   Process: com.appmovilperote, PID: 29566
>                   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void
> com.appmovilperote.AsyncTaskServicios.AsyncResponse.processFinish(java.lang.String)'
> on a null object reference
>                       at com.appmovilperote.AsyncTaskServicios.AsyncTaskDatos.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskDatos.java:48)
>                       at com.appmovilperote.AsyncTaskServicios.AsyncTaskDatos.onPostExecute(AsyncTaskDatos.java:25)
>                       at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
>                       at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
>                       at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
>                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
>                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5725)
>                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1030)
>                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:825)
```

**Splash**:

```
public class Splash extends Activity  implements AsyncResponse {

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

AsyncTaskDatos tel =  new AsyncTaskDatos(Splash.this);
            tel.execute();
 }

 @Override
    public void processFinish(String output){

        //Here you will receive the result fired from async class
        //of onPostExecute(result) method.
    }
}
```

**Asynctask**:

```
   public class AsyncTaskDatos extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        private ProgressDialog dialog;
        Splash activity;

        public AsyncResponse delegate = null;

        public AsyncTaskDatos(Splash activity) {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
            this.activity = activity;

        }


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog.setMessage("Cargando datos por favor espere");
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                delegate.processFinish(result);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String res = "1";

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return res;
        }
    }
}
```

**AsyncResponse**:

```
public interface AsyncResponse {
    void processFinish(String output);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

¿Cómo obtener el valor de retorno del método onPostExecute de mi AsyncTask en mi Activity?
Precisamente con una interfaz como la que declaras:

```
public interface AsyncResponse {
    void processFinish(String output);
}
```

Dentro de tu Asynctask defines una variable para la interfaz, que al terminar la ejecución del Asynctask en `onPostExecute()` se llamaría:

```
public class AsyncTaskDatos extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
  public AsyncResponse delegate = null;


   ...
   ...

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      delegate.processFinish(result);
    }
 }
```

tienes correcta esta parte, pero el problema esta mencionado en el error que indica :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void
>   com.appmovilperote.AsyncTaskServicios.AsyncResponse.processFinish(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

**esto quiere decir que la instancia de la interfaz `AsyncResponse` no esta inicializada!, Agrega un constructor que reciba esta instancia:**

```
public class AsyncTaskDatos extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
  public AsyncResponse delegate = null;

   public AsyncTaskDatos(AsyncResponse delegate){
    this.delegate = delegate;
   } 
  // Define interfaz.
  public interface AsyncResponse {
      void processFinish(String output);
  }

    ...
   ...

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      delegate.processFinish(result);
    }
 }
```

De esta forma en el método `processFinish()` de tu `Activity` obtendrías el valor obtenido en el método `onPostExecute()` de tu `Asynctask`:

```
public class Splash extends Activity  implements AsyncResponse {

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

  //AsyncTaskDatos tel =  new AsyncTaskDatos(Splash.this);
  // tel.execute();

   new AsyncTaskDatos(this).execute();

 }

 @Override
    public void processFinish(String output){

        //Here you will receive the result fired from async class
        //of onPostExecute(result) method.
    }
}
```

Comment: He echo exactamente igual todo como lo comentaba el post anterior y lo que me comentas pero aún así me sigue marcando el mismo error :s

Comment: justo cuando llega en este punto  delegate.processFinish(result); truena la aplicación

Comment: Constructor "public AsyncTaskDatos(AsyncResponse delegate){
    this.delegate = delegate;
   } "  is never used

Comment: "truena" porque delegate. tiene valor null.  Ve la linea que agregué a tu Activity;  new AsyncTaskDatos(this).execute(); con eso no debe decir que nunca es usado ;) trata y dime que obtienes.

Comment: Vale mi error era en el constructor, en el momento de crear mi objeto Asynctask desde mi Activity no pasaba el parámetro interfaz para que así en el Asynctask no lo marcara como null haha gracias Elena un saludo :D

Comment: Exactamente, que bien que todo quedo excelente, saludos!