# Pasar un objeto json de una activity a otra

Tags: java, android, json

tengo el siguiente problema estoy intentado traer una lista de elementos q obtengo de un `json`, desde una `activity` a traves de un `controlador` q lo solicita a una clase q posee el `json`. Dentro del codigo que adjunto lo que busco es pasar a mi `MainActivity` la lista de especialidades a traves de un método.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<Especialidad> ep;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Especialidad_connect e = new Especialidad_connect();
        e.execute("http://192.168.1.55:8080/especialidad/");
        ep = new ArrayList<>();
        final Consultas_Especialidad ce = new Consultas_Especialidad(MainActivity.this);
        ep = ce.getAll();
    }
}
```

Consulta_especialidad

```
public class Consultas_Especialidad {

     Context context;
     ArrayList<Especialidad> espList, lista;

    public Consultas_Especialidad(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

public void setLista(ArrayList<Especialidad> e){
    espList = new ArrayList<>();
    espList = e;
}

public ArrayList<Especialidad> getAll(){
    lista = new ArrayList<>();
    lista = espList;
    return lista;
    }

}
```

Especialidad_connect

```
public class Especialidad_connect extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


    public static Especialidad[]  especialidad_arreglo;
    public ArrayList<Especialidad> listaEspecialidades;
    Especialidad especialidad;

        @Override
        public String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            return GET(urls[0]);
        }

        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(String r) {
            listaEspecialidades = new ArrayList<>();
            especialidad = new Especialidad();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            especialidad_arreglo = gson.fromJson(r, Especialidad[].class);
            int t = especialidad_arreglo.length;
            for (int i=0; i < t; i++){
              especialidad.setId(especialidad_arreglo[i].getId());
              especialidad.setNombre(especialidad_arreglo[i].getNombre());
                listaEspecialidades.add(especialidad);
            }
            Consultas_Especialidad ce = new Consultas_Especialidad(null);
            ce.setLista(listaEspecialidades);
        }

    public static String GET(String url){
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";
        try {
            // create HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            // make GET request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
            // receive response as inputStream
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
            // convert inputstream to string
            if(inputStream != null)
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            else
                result = "Did not work!";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            result += line;
        inputStream.close();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola no se si sea la manera correcta, pero podrías pasarlo como parámetro extra  al activity y capturarlo como muestra esta respuesta, eso si la clase debe implementar Serializable https://stackoverflow.com/a/21250407/6083334

Comment: Al intentar usar Serializable me encuentro con un error en el `getIntent()` donde espera un `String`

Comment: Como lo estas haciendo?

Comment: Otra solucion mas rebuscada es que consultes a la api con retrofit, y luego guardes el json en una base de datos puede ser objectbox y solo pasas en el inten el id y luego consultas el objecto.

Comment: @RobertoFernandez lo que estoy buscando es utilizar una solucion enfocada en mvp, el problema esta en que el `AsyncTask` al trabajar de modo asincrono cuando hago la llamada al metodo `getAll` aun la sentencia donde cargaría el arreglo no llega a ejecutarse.  Estariía necesitando alguna forma si la hay de poder implementar `mvp` utilizando `AsyncTask`

Comment: Buscaste en la documentación de retrofit? puedes hacer la petición sincronía si es tu necesidad.leer asi sea por enésima de sobre una librería siempre es bueno.

Comment: Ahi aplique retrofit y aun asi no logro el resultado q espero [link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/135488/problema-para-enviar-json-entre-activitys-con-retorfit)

Comment: pero que no te sirve? el retrofit sincrono o que exactamente?

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que me respondiste en un comentario, buscas implementar una solucion mas enfocada a mvp. Si ese es el caso, te comento que te hacen falta unas cuantas cosas. Te dejare una respuesta para que no tengas que modificar tanto tu codigo y esta ligeramente mas enfocado a mvp, pero la estructura no deja de estar completa

```
interface MainActivityContract{
    interface View{
        void mostrarEspecialidades(ArrayList<Especialidad> especialidades);
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MainActivityContract.View {

    private Especialidad_connect e;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        e = new Especialidad_connect(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        e.execute("http://192.168.1.55:8080/especialidad/");
    }

    @Override
    void mostrarEspecialidades(ArrayList<Especialidad> especialidades){
        //todo, haz lo que tengas que hacer para mostrar tus especialidades
    }

}


public class Especialidad_connect extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    private MainActivityContract.View mView;
    .............

    public Especialidad_connect(MainActivityContract.View view){
        mView = view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String r) {
        listaEspecialidades = new ArrayList<>();
        //etc etc
        //estas ultimas 2 lineas estan de sobra, lo demas esta bien
        //Consultas_Especialidad ce = new Consultas_Especialidad(null);
        //ce.setLista(listaEspecialidades);
        mView.mostrarEspecialidades(listaEspecialidades);
```

El problema es que cuando haces el getAll, no es que no se haya ejecutado (tal vez ya se ejecuto, quien sabe), si no que tu dentro del doinbackground, haces una instancia de consulta_especialidad, en estas lineas

```
Consultas_Especialidad ce = new Consultas_Especialidad(null);
ce.setLista(listaEspecialidades);
```

y luego en el activity haces otra instancia diferente de consulta especialidad. A menos que lo manejes como singleton, no vas a obtener nunca nada. Entonces, si quieres usar algo mas enfocado a MVP, ten en cuenta que la capa de la vista, no debe de manejar nada de datos (en tu caso tienes declarado `ArrayList<Especialidad> ep;` que creo deberia ir en la capa del presentador.

Mi codigo no deja de tener errores/carencias por que implicaria un poco mas de cambio en varios lados, como primero un presentador, y ese presentador seria el encargado de mandar a llamar a ejecutar el asyctask, asi que te puedo recomendar esta lectura donde utilizan mvp y async task

[link](https://medium.com/@owaistnt/getting-most-out-of-asynctask-with-mvp-bfa9cacdf600)

Answer (score 0):

> lo que busco es pasar a mi MainActivity la lista de especialidades a
>   traves de un método.

en realidad puedes obtener los datos directamente de la ejecución de tu AsyncTask en la clase `MainActivity`, una opción es implementando una interfaz que obtenga los datos al terminar la ejecución del AsyncTask:

[¿Cómo obtener el valor de retorno del método onPostExecute de mi AsyncTask en mi Activity?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/43762/c%C3%B3mo-obtener-el-valor-de-retorno-del-m%C3%A9todo-onpostexecute-de-mi-asynctask-en-mi)

---

Implementas la interfaz `AsyncResponse` en tu `AsyncTask` y en el método `processFinish()` obtendrías el .json o el resultado de tu `AsyncTask` en tu `MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements AsyncResponse {

    ArrayList<Especialidad> ep;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Especialidad_connect e = new Especialidad_connect();
        e.execute("http://192.168.1.55:8080/especialidad/");
        ep = new ArrayList<>();
        final Consultas_Especialidad ce = new Consultas_Especialidad(MainActivity.this);
        ep = ce.getAll();
    }


      ...
      ...
    @Override
    public void processFinish(String resultado){

        //Aquí obtienes el resultado del AsyncTask.
    }


}
```

Comment: Podría traerlo directamente pero me interesa por una cuestión de diseño que primero sea obtenido por el controlador y q sea este quien lo envie a mi `MainActivity`. Donde através de un método q se encuentre en el controlador pueda obtenerlo en mi  `MainActivity`

Comment: Obtener como respuesta un .json y enviarlo entre actividades no creo que sea buena idea de diseño, más problemas si el ,json es extenso. Porque se  requiere enviar el json entre activities?, de hecho si es pequeño puedes enviarlo en el intent.

Comment: Por que la idea es q distitnas `Activitys` le puedan pedir a un `Controlador` un objeto determinado, y este `Controlador` haga la consulta al json q se encuentra en lo q seria la clase `Especialidad_connect`.

Comment: Cual sería la clase Controlador?, ok Germanccho, eso indica que los datos quedarían en memoria listos para ser consultados por diferentes actividades.

Comment: me suena a que buscas una solucion enfocada a mvp o algo parecido?

Comment: @YorchSircam justamente es lo que estoy buscando utilizar una solucion enfocada en mvp, el problema esta en que el `AsyncTask` al trabajar de modo asincrono cuando hago la llamada al metodo `getAll` aun la sentencia donde cargaría el arreglo no llega a ejecutarse.  Estariía necesitando alguna forma si la hay de poder implementar `mvp` utilizando `AsyncTask`