# Problema para enviar json entre Activitys con retorfit

Tags: android, json, api, retrofit

tengo el siguiente problema estoy intentado traer una lista de objetos q obtengo de un `json`, desde una activity a traves de un controlador. Dentro del codigo que adjunto lo que busco es pasar a mi MainActivity la lista de especialidades a traves de un método.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MainActivityView {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Controlador ctr = new Controlador(this);
        ctr.getAll();
    }
    @Override
    public void mostrarEspecialidades(ArrayList<Especialidad> especialidades) {

        ArrayList<Especialidad> esp = especialidades;
    }
    @Override
    public void errorCargarEspecialidades(String error) {

    }
}
```

Controlador

```
    public class Controlador {

    ArrayList<Especialidad> lista ;

    private MainActivityView mView;
    public Controlador(MainActivityView view) {
        mView = view;
    }

    public void getAll(){
        Api c = new Api(mView);
        c.cargarEspecialidades();
    }

    public void setDatos(ArrayList<Especialidad> datos){
        lista = datos;
    }

}
```

Api

```
   public class Api implements Callback<ArrayList<Especialidad>> {

    public static final String base_url = "http://192.168.1.55:8080/";

    private MainActivityView mView;
    public Api(MainActivityView view){
        mView = view;
    }

    public void cargarEspecialidades() {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(base_url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
        EspecialidadService servicio = retrofit.create(EspecialidadService.class);
        Call<ArrayList<Especialidad>> call = servicio.getEspecialidad();
        call.enqueue(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<ArrayList<Especialidad>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
        if(response.isSuccess()){
            Controlador c = new Controlador(null);
            ArrayList<Especialidad> a = response.body();
            c.setDatos(a);
            mView.mostrarEspecialidades(a);
    }else {
            mView.errorCargarEspecialidades(String.valueOf(response.errorBody()));
            System.out.println(response.errorBody());}
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

    }
}
```

MainActivityView

```
public interface MainActivityView {

    void mostrarEspecialidades(ArrayList<Especialidad> especialidades);
    void errorCargarEspecialidades(String error);
}
```

Comment: y el problema cual es?

Comment: si te fijas en el Main haces esto   instancias la Clase Controlador, y en la clase Api en el public void onResponse tambien instancias otro Controlador, como desde el Main vas a obtener getAll si la instancia es diferente de la que estas usando en la Api.

Comment: @RobertoFernandez ahi instancie una sola vez al `controlador` desde el main y utilizo el mismo controlador desde la `api`, aun asi sigo sin obtener mi lista en el main.

Comment: @BrunoSosaFastTag obtener una lista en el main, utilizando mvp, donde pido desde mi main todos las especialidades al controlador, y espero a que este me envie dicha lista q lo saca desde la api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es mas o menos lo mismo que te comente en tu pregunta anterior
[link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/135007/pasar-un-objeto-json-de-una-activity-a-otra)

Tienes que crear una interfaz con los metodos que tenga tu vista, esa referencia, almacenarla a tu controlador y por ultimo, mandarla en tu API y utilizar esa referencia cuando ya tengas el resultado de tu peticion de retrofit, no sin antes convertir la respuesta a un arreglo o algo mas manejable.

```
interface MainActivityView{
    void mostrarEspecialidades(ArrayList<Especialidad> especialidades);
    void errorCargarEspecialidades(String error);   
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MainActivityView{
    ......
    ......
    Controlador ctr = new Controlador(this);
    ctr.getAll(); //getAll no regresa nada


public class Controlador{
    private MainActivityView mView;
    public Controlador(MainActivityView view){
       mView=view;
    }

    public void /*ArrayList<Especialidad>*/ getAll(){
        Api c = new Api(mView);
        c.cargarEspecialidades();
        //listita = lista;
        //return listita;
    }

.........

public class Api implements Callback<ArrayList<Especialidad>> {
    private MainActivityView mView;
    public Api(MainActivityView view){
        mView = view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<ArrayList<Especialidad>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
    if(response.isSuccess()){
        ArrayList<Especialidad> especialidades = miFuncionMagica(response.body)
        mView.mostrarEspecialidades(especialidades);
        //t = response.body();
        //Controlador ctr = new Controlador();
        //ctr.setLista(t);
    }else{
        /*Esto que voy a poner es extra pero te puede ser util*/
        mView.errorCargarEspecialidades(response.errorBody());
        System.out.println(response.errorBody());
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahi subí el código con las modificaciones correspondientes q resuelven mi problema.