# android - ¿Qué significa flushPendingCommands() de la clase Binder?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Cuando estoy ejecutando una tarea `AsyncTask`, ésta se queda como ejecutando y nunca termina su ejecución, pese a que completa todo lo declarado en `doInBackground(Params...)`. En otras palabras, siempre se queda en estado `AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING`, por lo que nunca nunca sale de este ciclo:

```
protected WebAsyncTask<Req, Res> wsConsumer;

// Más código y un método
    this.wsConsumer.execute(request);
    do {
        response = this.wsConsumer.get();
    } while (!this.wsConsumer.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED));
```

La declaración de la clase `WebAsyncTask` es la siguiente:

```
public class WebAsyncTask<Req, Res> extends AsyncTask<Req, Void, Res>
```

Revisando su [código fuente](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r55/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java), he encontrado que, al momento de ejecutar la tarea en segundo plano, invoca lo siguiente, en la línea 334:

```
    result = doInBackground(mParams);
    Binder.flushPendingCommands();
```

Por lo que mi duda es la siguiente, ¿qué es lo que hace `Binder.flushPendingCommands()` exactamente y cómo hago para evitar que la instancia `AsyncTask` se quede invocando ese métodoc como en un ciclo infinito, y continúe con el `onPostExecute`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿qué es lo que hace Binder.flushPendingCommands() exactamente?

Como puedes ver en el còdigo fuente, se obtiene el resultado de la tarea asincrona y posteriormente se llama `Binder.flushPendingCommands()`, la funcion que realiza este mètodo es garantizar la liberaciòn de las referencias de objetos creadas durante en el proceso y que ya no son necesarios.

```
public Result call() throws Exception {
                mTaskInvoked.set(true);
                Result result = null;
                try {
                    Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
                     //Obtiene resultado de tarea asincrona.
                    result = doInBackground(mParams);
                    //Libera referencias de objetos.
                    Binder.flushPendingCommands();
                } catch (Throwable tr) {
                    mCancelled.set(true);
                    throw tr;
                } finally {
                    postResult(result);
                }
                return result;
            }
```

Si no se realizara este llamado y tuvieras el llamado de varias tareas podrìas estar reteniendo objetos innecesariamente y mas tiempo del necesario lo cual podrìa causar un problema de consumo de memoria.

Con respecto a tu pregunta:

> ¿cómo hago para evitar que la instancia AsyncTask se quede invocando
>   ese método como en un ciclo infinito, y continúe con el
>   onPostExecute?

En realidad esto me parece incorrecto:

```
  this.wsConsumer.execute(request);
    do {
        response = this.wsConsumer.get();
    } while (!this.wsConsumer.getStatus().equals(AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED));
```

Deberìas simplemente llamar el `Asynctask` pero si deseas que se obtenga el valor obtenido en `onPostExecute()`, realizalo de esta forma:

```
response = this.wsConsumer.execute(request).get();
```

---

Considera revisar tambien:

[¿Cómo obtener el valor de retorno del método onPostExecute de mi AsyncTask en mi Activity?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/43762/c%c3%b3mo-obtener-el-valor-de-retorno-del-m%c3%a9todo-onpostexecute-de-mi-asynctask-en-mi)

[¿Como obtener el valor de un AsyncTask? Esperar hasta obtener el resultado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/124662/como-obtener-el-valor-de-un-asynctask-esperar-hasta-obtener-el-resultado)